# database entities and their dependency wrt local info. Correct design?

Tags: design-patterns

Sorry for the wacky title, I need a careful explanation to clarify what I mean.

Suppose I have a database (intended as a trivial collection), whose role is to hold a set of objects and return them on demand. Example, I have a FooDatabase holding objects of type Foo. These Foo objects are loaded from a file, under the coordination of the FooDatabase.

Now, it happens that additional information must be stored in the Foo objects. This additional information is not available on the file, but it is pertinent to each Foo. Technically, if this information is self-detailed within the realm of responsibility of each Foo, there would be no real problem: each Foo computes the information, and stores it on itself.

Unfortunately, my case is more complicated: this information does not only depend on the Foo on topic, but also on some other Foo objects stored in the database. I would have two possibilities to solve this problem:

1. I pass the database itself to the Foo object, so that Foo can query the database to look for the other Foo objects needed to compute the information
2. I delegate the responsibility of computing this information to the database object, which is the only one able to see the "whole picture". Once the information is computed for every Foo, it is pushed into each of them by the database. The Foo objects hold a dummy information until this happens.

Did you already meet this problem, and what is the agreed design for such case?

Comment: How is the "look for the other Foo objects needed" information recorded? What about returning Foo object "A" along with a list of related Foo objects allowing the newly born Foo object "A" to query the DB for the missing info?

Comment: @p.marino : I have Foo("one") and Foo("two"), but I also have Foo("one", "two"), which "depends" on the first two in order to compute additional info.

Comment: Can you add some behaviour to the DB so that it can return the list of dependencies for each node (empty for foo[1] and foo[2], and listing ["1","2"] for foo[1,2]? And allow foo[1,2] to query the DB for any additional info based on the list itself?

Comment: @p.marino : I have two problems with this solution. The first is that I don't really like the idea of an object contained in the db to query the db itself, because the query could happen as the db is being constructed. I tend to stay away from circular dependencies. The second problem is that everything is coded in fortran, so I don't have a lot of flexibility in implementation, although this is a design problem and as such, language independent.

Comment: So the "DB" is really a generic, formless data store? I.e. it could be a file, a map, a JavaSpaces instance... and the problem should not consider it as internally consistent in any given moment? In the sense that it could be updated from a different thread/process? Wouldn't this make impossible to be sure you had all the required info to build any FOO? If this is the case having the "DB" push info to the Foos would probably work better, then. Basically make each FOO a listener (for itself) and DB a publisher of update events.

Answer (score 0):

What you call the database I see as something similar to the [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) would provide an interface for operations to query for a given Foo from the underlying data store.  The Foo objects simply hold the data and provide methods for retrieving it.  In my experience, you have 2 options that would apply based on how often you need the related Foo objects.

**Option 1: Builder**

If you need them most of the time would use the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to handle this situation.  You have a FooBuilder that uses the operations provided by the Database to query the database and fill the required data on the Foo object.  Whenever you need a particular Foo, you call the Builder, which generates a fully filled Foo for your use.

**Option 2: Lazy Loading**

If you don't need the related Foo data very often, you can implement a Lazy Loading solution.  This can be done using the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).  In order to implement this, you have a method BuildUnfilledFoo on your FooBuilder that only loads the initial Foo and provides an UnfilledState.  UnfilledState implements the methods that require the additional data by first replacing itself with a FilledState by getting the other Foos needed, and then calling the FilledState to carry out the operations.

Here are my thoughts on the other options you presented:

**pass the database itself to the Foo object**

- As you pointed out in the comments, you are introducing a circular dependency into the application.
- You make your data objects dependent on your database implementation, which will make it harder to change data implementations in the future.

**Delegate the responsibility of computing this information to the database**

- This makes the database the owner for the business logic associated with the construction of the data objects, when it should really only handle data queries